# Phonegap build windows phone 7 app tile title

Tags: windows-phone-7, phonegap-build

when i pin my pgb wp7 project to the start screen the tile title is cordova_1.5.0etc

how do i change it?

Is there a way to do this in the config .xml?

Answer (score 1):

In The WMManifest.xml file of WP7 project, change the value of  Title tag

```
<Tokens>
      <PrimaryToken TokenID="_7versionappToken" TaskName="_default">
        <TemplateType5>
          <BackgroundImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Background.png</BackgroundImageURI>
          <Count>0</Count>
          **<Title>MyTileID</Title>**
        </TemplateType5>
      </PrimaryToken>
    </Tokens>
```